# Exception: Action not allowed

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-docs, docx-mailmerge

I am trying to create a google apps script mail merge that pulls data from a google sheets to populate fields in a google document. I am receiving the following error:

```
Exception: action not allowed
```

I am the owner of all scripts, sheets, and docs involved in this script. I read something about being logged into multiple google accounts causing this issue, but I logged out of my personal google account (this script is with for work account), so that I had only one account active, and the issue persisted.

Here is my code:

```
function createLetters() {
  //Ids for docs and sheets 
  var docTemplateId = "1PBm3Oghmtf7ZPWolCIY9xGkEyW3l3jR4_3olDDaBvMk";
  var docFinalId = "1fgg_nX-IaN4xOwN7rwey3EX_pGatF136P8GlG0u299w";
  var docFinalId = DocumentApp.create('El Letters').getId();
  var ssID = "1DlWAglK8IJwLtBSH-kUtg3rH6bmuS-MGhl0R7JalM5Q";

  //Get the docs and sheet 
  var docTemplate = DocumentApp.openById(docTemplateId);
  var docFinal = DocumentApp.openById(docFinalId);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("ELPA Scores");

  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  Logger.log(data)
  var templateParagraphs = docTemplate.getBody().getParagraphs();
  
  docFinal.getBody().clear()

  

   for(var i =0;i < data.length;i++){
    createMailMerge(data[i][0],data[i][1],data[i][2],data[i][3],data[i][4],data[i][5],data[i][6],data[i][7],data[i][8],data[i][9],templateParagraphs,docFinal)
  }
}

function createMailMerge(
  firstname,
  lastname,
  school,
  level,
  r,
  w,
  s,
  l,
  status,
  test_date,
  templateParagraphs,
  docFinal){

    templateParagraphs.forEach(function(p){
      docFinal.getBody().appendParagraph(p.copy()
            .replaceText("{{first_name}}", firstname)
            .replaceText('{{last_name}}', lastname)
            .replaceText("{{school}}", school)
            .replaceText("{{level}}",level)
            .replaceText("{{r}}", r)
            .replaceText("{{w}}", w)
            .replaceText("{{s}}", s)
            .replaceText("{{l}}", l)
            .replaceText("{{status}}",status)
            .replaceText("{{test_date}}", test_date)
            //.replaceText("{{contacted_date}}", contacted_date)
          )
        });

      docFinal.getBody().appendPageBreak()
 
}
```

This feels like a fairly straightforward script, so I'm not sure why I'm encountering this issue. Do I need to incorporate a way to have it get more permissions?

Comment: Can you verify of confirm if you have editor access to all files and folders that you are trying to access via script?

Comment: Yes, I am the owner and creator of all docs and sheets involved in this script.

Comment: Usually that error pops up whenever you are running the script that involves accessing a file or folder that the user who is initiated or ran the script doesn't have any access to, so I would suggest you could try to double check which user account has access to which file/folder.

Comment: Okay I will give that a try.

Comment: All the files and folders involved in this script are owned by me and located inside my drive. Could there be another possible reason why the script is behaving in this way?